# How to translate from SQL to NoSQL/MapReduce?

Tags: sql, database, nosql, couchdb, mapreduce

I have a background working with relational databases but recently started to dabble in CouchDB and was surprised by how some non-relational operations, which would be simple in SQL, were not first-class functions in CouchDB.

I would appreciate you taking a moment to map each SQL statement below to its MapReduce equivalent.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE price < 20.00;
SELECT category, SUM(price) FROM products GROUP BY category;
UPDATE products SET price = 19.99 WHERE price = 20.00;
DELETE FROM products WHERE expires_at <= NOW();
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `SELECT` commands are pretty easy. Bulk writes are a bit more complicated. Generally, you'll use some view to retrieve the documents that need to be changed, then you'll use the [`_bulk_docs`](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API) API to send all the changes at once.

Also, consult the [documentation regarding views](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API) for details for how to issue queries. This includes ordering, grouping, etc.

---

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE price < 20.00;`

### Map

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.price < 20) {
    emit(doc.price);
  }
}
```

### Reduce

```
_count
```

If you need this to work with an arbitrary amount, not just 20, then you'll need to emit the price in all cases, and use `startkey` and `endkey` to narrow down your resultset.

---

`SELECT category, SUM(price) FROM products GROUP BY category;`

### Map

```
function (doc) {
  emit(doc.category, doc.price);
}
```

### Reduce

```
_sum
```

This map function essentially uses the category as the key, with the price as the value in your key/value pair. The reduce function will add up the prices for each different key.

---

`UPDATE products SET price = 19.99 WHERE price = 20.00;`

### Map

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.price == 20) {
    emit(doc.price);
  }
}
```

Once your application pulls down the contents of this view, you'll perform all the manipulations in your application code, then send back the results into the database via the `_bulk_docs` API.

---

`DELETE FROM products WHERE expires_at <= NOW();`

### Map

```
function (doc) {
  emit(doc.expires_at);
}
```

Depending on how your store your date-time values, you may need to adjust the map function as well as your query to the view. Using a timestamp (JS uses milliseconds instead of seconds) is probably the fastest way to accomplish this. Once you've set up your query, you'll add a new field to each of these documents. `_deleted: true`. Once you send this list back into the database (again with `_bulk_docs`) all the specified documents will be deleted.

Comment: Is anything like this available on DynamoDB?